# How to cleanup unused azure resources

Tags: azure

I have a task to clean up unused resources in an Azure subscription. There are 600 odd resources in total. 
I prefer to do this through a script(power-shell?) as I have to repeat this activity in multiple subscriptions.

To start with may be I could,

-> Fetch all the resources with last updated/activity time < 30 days
or Fetch all the resources with no CPU utilization in last 30 days
-> Review the list
-> Delete the resources

Has anyone did this already? I'm keen to know various ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do with Azure function with Powershell, you will need to create a timer function to automate the job.

There is an interesting blog post on  [Use Azure Function to Clean-up your Mess, Automatically](https://dev.to/azure/use-azure-function-to-clean-up-your-mess-automatically-3h29) and the corresponding **[`repository`](https://github.com/FBoucher/AzSubscriptionCleaner)**