# Fetch all resources list which have been not used 30/60 days

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I am looking PowerShell script that can fetch all Azure resources list that has been not used for 30/60 days.
eg. App service, Service bus, blob storage, disk, Virtual machine, etc.

Comment: What have you tried so far? BTW, it will be extremely complicated to get this list as "used criteria" for each resource type is going to be very different.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59132346/how-to-cleanup-unused-azure-resources

Comment: @Sajeetharan nice link but it totally avoids the difficulty of determining whether a resource is active or not.